# save multiple inputs in middle table with same name Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am allowing users to add multiple subjects on the fly while adding a student, for example when you are adding a student you can add a subject i.e Math then you will set its attributes teacher name, credit hours etc. But when saving to db I need to save the information to my middle table `students_subjects`

`id | student_id | subject_id | teacher_name | credit_hours`

[image: user can add multiple fields like this]

The problem is that how I can save the information for each subject. I can save the subject_id in a hidden field and get that but how would I know that this id is related to that particular subject and get the teacher and credit hours for that id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**how I can save the information for each subject**

```
DB::table('students_subjects')->insert([
    'student_id' => $input['studentId'],
    'subject_id' => $input['subjectId'],
    'teacher_name' => $input['teacherName'],
    'credit_hours' => $input['creditHours'],
]);
```

**I can save the subject_id in a hidden field and get that but how would I know that this id is related to that particular subject**

If you have the subject_id - then you know what subject it relates to.

**get the teacher and credit hours for that id**

```
$result = DB::table('students_subjects')
->select(['teacher_name', 'credit_hours'])
->where('id', $id)
->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have 3 tables. And a many-many relationship

- students
- subjects
- student_subject

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many to learn about defining your eloquent models.

From your question, I would consider changing how you structure your database.

A student `hasMany` subjects. A subject belongsTo teacher.

So I would have 4 tables as follows:

```
students
    - id
    - first_name
    - last_name
student_subject
    - student_id
    - subject_id
    - credit_hours (assuming this is the number of hours the student has studied?)
subjects
    - id
    - name
    - credit_hours (assuming this is the total credit value)
teachers
    - id
    - name
    - subject_id
```

If a teacher can teach many subjects, then you would need to add a `subject_teacher` pivot table.

When adding the student, if you could provide a dropdown list of subjects whose value is the subject_id, then when you select the subject - you post the subject_id back to php ready to insert into the DB.

Comment: My structure can not be this, I am seeking solution for my problem asked in the question actually.

Comment: Apologies, I misunderstood what you want because the question is poorly written and a bit cryptic. I will try adding another answer, but in the meantime, help us to help you by re phrasing your question to make it easier to understand.